# My Wifi is nearly half the speed of my ethernet

Tags: router, internet, wireless-router, internet-connection, internet-speed

I just got a new plan with 30Mbps download and 5Mbps Upload. I get just that on Ethernet connection to my Desktop, however, my Laptop or mobile phone get only 13-20mpbs even when staying next to the router. It's a 300mbps router, so it should be fine. However, the upload is the same both through Ethernet or Wi-Fi, ~4.7mbps which is right by my plan. Here are my router WLAN settings... any help please?

[WLAN settings Part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlhGN.jpg)

[WLAN settings Part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLQRT.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

OK so there are a few things this could be.

Firstly are your phone and laptop 2.4n compatible.

Real world expectations of 2.4n (300mbps) are 150mbps, which is 18.75Mbps.

More details here: https://www.centurylink.com/home/help/internet/wireless/which-frequency-should-you-use.html

Sounds like you are getting real world speeds.

Perhaps you need to switch to a 5Ghz router. Things get even more complex then about actual speeds. I won't try and explain here.

Comment: Slight units correction: *” (300**M**bps) are 150**M**bps, which is 18.75M**B**ps.*” also, “*5G**H**z*”. Sorry, could not resist...

Answer (score 0):

Basically I think the answer here boils down to “WiFi is terrible.” It is also possible that your router simply can’t handle the speed. The WiFi standard you are on is older, and could be the issue. In order maintain the integrity of the data that is being transmitted, routers will slow down the data rate the further and further from the router you get. This is why downloads are slower standing further away. Older standards of WiFi like yours is couldn’t handle as much as newer ones. There is also the issue of signal stability. I would suggest that your issue is just a router that is too old.

A few things that I would try are; a firmware update, verify that you are using the 5 GHz band, and ensure that the router is set to its fastest transfer speed in the router settings.

Comment: You should use inversed square law to explain why the further from router the weaker the signal gets...